# How to make sure that all nodes have acknowledged a new job in cluster mode?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler, distributed-computing

I am running Quartz on cluster mode and I'm using it to execute asynchronous tasks in a distributed architecture.

When I use `SimpleTrigger` to schedule a job at a particular time (let's say in 10 seconds), how do I make sure that the current node is not the only one aware of the new scheduling? As far as I know, the nodes are aware of each other only via the database, which means they can't communicate in real time. Does that mean I have to notify other nodes to reload the job store in order to make this solution work? If so, how do I force a job store reload with code (assuming I managed to notify the nodes by other means)?

Answer (score 0):

Quartz clusters use pulling for node communication. So you have to adjust [`org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval`](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html) according to your needs:

> org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval
>
> Set the frequency (in milliseconds) at which this instance “checks-in”* with the other instances of the cluster. Affects the quickness of detecting failed instances.

Say you set it to 2 seconds (2000 millis). Then your healthy nodes should be aware of jobs that trigger in more than, for instance, 3 seconds in the future.

Comment: OK so the check-in is a health check and also a job store refresh?

Comment: With the risk of over simplifying, the scheduler consumes triggers "as fast as it can": https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/core/QuartzSchedulerThread.java#L287. Then if you check-in every 2 seconds and they failed you make sure the triggers get picked by another node. Are you experience a specific issue? Maybe you can add more details to the question and the answer  can be more specific. Details on cluster options: https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Comment: No specific issue I just wonder if this library fits my needs. I found nothing saying clearly that a the `org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval` parameter is about check-in, which includes node availability for job execution **and** syncing the jobs scheduled by other nodes.

Comment: The link that I shared explains it's about check-in and by reducing it you increase the quickness of detecting failed nodes. If you take a look at the code you see it basically check-in it's healthy and tries to process failed tasks. Apart from that each node tries to acquire triggers whenever they have capacity. So by having low cluster interval you make sure your jobs gets executed "in time", even if one node fails.